# I am getting following error can anybody guide what exactly it is?

Tags: java, spring-ws

```
DEBUG [client.core.WebServiceTemplate] Received error for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]
ERROR [core.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler] Unknown Error has happened{Actual Message- org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Proxy Error [502]}
com.hcentive.core.exception.ServiceFailureException: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Proxy Error [502]
    at com.cvty.ws.service.AppWebServiceClientImpl.marshalSendAndReceive(AppWebServiceClientImpl.java:129)
    at com.hps.service.HPSServiceClientImpl.getAck(HPSServiceClientImpl.java:131)
    at com.hps.ws.HPSStatusManagerJob.updateStatus(HPSStatusManagerJob.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Proxy Error [502]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:627)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:551)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:351)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:345)
    at com.cvty.ws.service.AppWebServiceClientImpl.marshalSendAndReceive(AppWebServiceClientImpl.java:120)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to add more details to this question. And tag it appropriately for better response. I'm assuming this is a java question?

Comment: can anybody help me out what goes wrong?

Comment: i am trying to implement client side Message level security using Spring WS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy Error 502 (Bad Gateway). Looks like your app cannot reach the web service you are trying to access. Check the URL you are trying to access.